# How to generate a unique "id" for a model and its relations?

Tags: java, sql

Lets say i have three entities: `Order`, `OrderLine`, `OrderLineInfo`

Now I would like to generate an id which I can store on the `Order` so next time another order is created I can take a look in the database and see if an identical order was created. Identical means same stuff and quantity. Without the id I would have to select all orders, lines and so on and do a compare.

Is there some kind of best practice for generating an id like this?

Comment: You can solve this in your DB using `Unique`

Comment: Sounds interesting, could you provide a little more info?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of examples of using UNIQUE

```
CREATE TABLE hr.persons(
    person_id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(255),
    UNIQUE(email) //#cannot have two records that share the same email
);

CREATE TABLE hr.persons(
    person_id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(255),
    UNIQUE(first_name, last_name) //#cannot have two records that share the same first_name and last_name
);
```

Comment: ahh ok yes Im aware of that. I thought you ment something else by unique. But cant see how that will solve my problem here. My problem is generating the Id I can use. Lets say I have an order where someone orders two hammers and a shovel. Then another order is about to be created but before saving it I want to check if an order was already created with the same content. How would you generate an Id I can search for?

Comment: You can generate a `uuid` and store that save those order details in a session (if you are using a web application) or cache (if you are using a client application).

Comment: @OleBille What I am saying is that your can auto-generate an ID in the database, but use the constraint so that if you try to re-enter the same order, the constraint will prevent that, and then all you need to do is handle the Exception coming from the Database. IMO this is the best way to achieve what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a method similar to or even `hashCode()`. Implement it for all three entities including exactly the data you need for your identity check.

Finally add a column to your Order entity table holding the hashcode value and put an index on it (no unique one except you want to prohibit two identical orders in your database). Now you can simply look for an identical order searching for that hashcode.

Make sure the columns value is always up to date. If the ORM is using getter and setters you may delegate the getter to use `hashCode()` and simply ignore the setter.

Don’t forget to override `equals()` if you use `hashCode()` to not break the Java language contract!

Comment: This is somewhat what Im looking for. But my challenge is how do I make a unique value based on two or more fields in a list. If I generate hash values I can easely get a dublicated value.